# How to extend the Diagonal Object in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js

I have been digging into rendering tree layouts in d3.js but I was wondering what the best practices are for extending the code that's already there?

For example if I wanted to use a straight line instead of a cubic bezier in the svg.diagonal.js file.  What would be the most effcient way of extending that code?

EDIT: It has been pointed out that this question has already been answered.  I wanted to add as a side note that a part of the hiccup for me was not being able to edit d3.js right off the bat because of the "illegal character error" dealt with here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1006